# Adding lists to existing nested lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

I'm very close to adding a flanking lists to my nested list but I can't seem to get it to work. I am currently using this code.

```
glider = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
border = []
for i in range (len(glider[0])):
    border.append(0)
glider.insert(i,border)
glider.append(border)
```

This would print `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`. I however wanted it to print `[[0,0,0],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[0,0,0]]`. Is there a way I could modify my existing code to do this? Thank you.

Edit: Glider is a varying nested list where there could be as many lists or characters in the list. However each list will always have the same number of characters compared to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the execution of the `for` loop, `i` is 2, so you are actually inserting the border at index `2`, after the glider content.

You should just pass `0` to `list.insert`:

```
glider.insert(0, border)
glider.append(border)
```

This will add the border to the beginning and to the end.

Note that you can simplify the “border creation” and get rid of the loop if you just do `border = [0] * len(glider[0])`:

```
glider = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

glider.insert(0, [0] * len(glider[0]))
glider.append([0] * len(glider[0]))
```

Comment: Why not just `n = len(glider[0])` `glider = [[0] * n] + glider + [[0] * n]`?